# what is the best time i can get for registration operation in python?

Tags: python, registration, tornado, crypt

in registration operation, there is a password crypt which as i understand can't parallelized since if it makes an operation of a key derivation (PBKDF2 for example), then it needs the previous value, then i guess it is a linear operation?

Making this process slow, is benefic for a user, since his password will be stronger for bruteforce for example, but there is another problem: DOS attack! if each operation of registration takes 1 second, then using a load balancer like NGinx will handle 8 simultanuous registration operation every second, which blocks the application? and if we add other operations, say: 2 seconds, then the application is not good?

So, any suggestions? using Tornado will not solve the problem since Tornado -as i understand- makes asynchronous operations in I/O operations...

Comment: "Making this process slow, is benefic for a user, since his password will be stronger for bruteforce for example" - no, security = breaking is much harder doing sth. with password.

Comment: @User sorry i dont understand?

Comment: I do not understand why "Making this process slow, is benefic for a user" especially why " his password will be stronger for bruteforce". Could you please explain this below you question?

Comment: @User it is about algorithms, using a simple MD5 hash is fast (for the sign in function), but weak, using Scrypt with lot of iteration is slow, but stronger.

Comment: Use SHA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm it is fast

Comment: i've trying SHA2 (pbkdf2-sha512) but it seems that SCrypt or BCrypt are better, but implemented in C, python will be slow on them

Comment: @User It is fast, but not so reslient against brute-force attacks, even with salting. The guy with his GPU or FPGA will break it quite fast (if it's a bad password). Nowadays, using algorithms which need not only time but also a lot of different memory access and quite some memory are a more efficient guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) functions like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) allow you to control the time it takes to hash the password by adjusting the iteration count (or other equivalent parameters for other functions).  You're correct in observing that there's a tradeoff here between making passwords hard to crack by brute force and avoiding DoS attacks.  You'll need to choose an iteration count to balance these two considerations.

Do keep in mind that modern CPUs can calculate millions of hash iterations per second.  Even if you use an iteration count of, say, only 1000, that still makes cracking the passwords 1000 times harder than not iterating the hash at all, even though hashing a single password with 1000 iterations only takes about a millisecond.

There are also other ways in which you can avoid or mitigate login DoS attacks.  For example, you could implement IP-based throttling, so that each IP address can only make some limited number of login attempts per minute.  Of course, distributed DoS attacks can get around that, but it's still a hurdle for any potential attacker to overcome.

Also, if you implement [login anti-CSRF tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412813/do-login-forms-need-tokens-against-csrf-attacks) (and you should), they'll also protect you against certain simple types of login DDoS attacks by requiring an extra round trip to fetch the token before any login attempt can be made.  [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)s can be another useful way to deal with login DoS attempts.  Finally, you may want to restrict all login requests to a separate set of servers and/or processes, with appropriate resource limits, so that even a successful DoS attack on the login form won't take down the *rest* of your site.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could even require the client to submit a cryptographic [proof of work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) more or less equivalent to the effort of hashing the password.  For example, you could send the client a random string and require it to send back a suffix to that string such that the random string plus the suffix hash to a value ending with *n* zero bits, where 2<sup>*n*</sup> is approximately your iteration count.  There exist [JavaScript crypto libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+crypto+library) that you could use to implement the client side of such a system.

Comment: This is a quite perfect answer.

Comment: but, even long logins will take the CPU so it's a kind of DOS?