# How to send a custom header as well as header location?

Tags: php, authentication, header, token

I'm trying to introduce a token to prevent CSRF in the login form since I reviewed some post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412813/do-login-forms-need-tokens-against-csrf-attacks) where it was said it's recommended. The way I send the token inside the logged area is through headers. (I've to do it on that way).

the login form is "as always":

login.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = 'the_token_string';
  header('X-CSRF-Token: '.$_SESSION['csrf_token']);//I'm not sure if is really neccessary to set this header here).
?>

<html>
<form method="post" action="flogin.php">
  <input type="text" name="user"/>
  <input type="password" name="pass"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token'] ?>"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

In the file the data is received, I check everything is fine about user name, password and token. In case the user logs succesfully, I just redirect him/her to the main page. Let's call main.php

flogin.php

```
//irrelevant code. Everything is fine.
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
header('Location: main.php');
exit;
```

Now, in main.php the first thing I've to do (it's a must) is check if user is really logged and also check the token.

main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'] || !$_SESSION['logged'])){
    header('Location: logout.php');
    exit;
}

$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) || !isset($headers['X-CSRF-Token']) || $headers['X-CSRF-Token']!=$_SESSION['csrf_token']){
    header('Location: logout.php');
    exit;
}
...
?>
```

And here is where I'm having the problem. Since the *header ('Location: main.php')* in the flogin.php file is before any output and it directly redirects to main.php, and the first thing I've to do there among other things is to check about the header with the token I always get the problem  the header is not already set.

I don't know how to send that header with the token value to main.php. I'm very stuck with this problem and I even don't know if this is the right way.

I googled about this but everything I found was about curl and I don't use curl at all (unless this becomes a must).

(I apologize about the code errors, if there's. I'm wrote it at raw).

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Just because you send a X-CSRF-Token HTTP header to the client/browser does not mean the client/browser wil send a X-CSRF-Token HTTP header back.  What are you running on the client/browser side that might send it back, Angualr, or something else?    Even if it does, it may not reach your Apache server if it is behind another proxy server of some sorts (some hosting companies like Webfaction will front-end your Apache with a shared nginx instance).

Comment: @BareNakedCoder The only point where I have problems is this one. I send the token back to the client when this is checked on main.php with the headers, so that's not the problem.