# Is CSRF token necessary in the login page of an OpenID-Connect authentication server?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, csrf, openid-connect

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I know that the lack of CSRF token in login page could lead to privacy violations(according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412813/do-login-forms-need-tokens-against-csrf-attacks)). However what I am concerned about is that could it lead to any new vulnerability in an authentication server's login page?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice. But I think the question is limited to a specific problem(The security vulnerabilities of not having a CSRF token in an authentication server's login page in OpenID-Connect). I would gladly edit the post if you specify which part of the question is vague or does not have enough details.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that protections against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) are required, but having to use CSRF *tokens* is not necessarily required. These tokens are a typical and common solution, but anything that keeps the user safe from this attack should be adequate.

So, stepping back, [OWASP says](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf):

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they’re currently authenticated.

Their [CSRF cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) has a number of possible protections (including non-token-based options). Some or all of these are what an OpenID Connect provider should support:

- Use of only [SameSite cookies](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#samesite-cookie-attribute) or a SameSite maker cookie to track cross-site requests
- Use of [custom headers](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers) in the request
- [Verification of the origin](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#verifying-origin-with-standard-headers) using standard headers
- Use of [double submit cookies](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie)
- Never changing state in a GET request

Also, don't forget to also protect against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) or else some of these protections can be defeated. That can be done using CSP and [other techniques](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).