# Do I need CSRF protection for /login endpoint?

Tags: rest, authentication, csrf, csrf-token

#### **I know**

this question has already been asked so many times, but after hours of searching I still don't have a clear answer to my problem.

Even projects like https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf have been abandoned and have not answered to new questions and doubts over the years like [this](https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf/issues/6).

#### **PROBLEM**

Let's say I have:

- a back-end on `back.domain.com` and
- a front-end on `front.domain.com`.

My back-end is a simply nodejs app with these rest endpoints:

1. `POST /login`:

   1. accepts JSON body like: `{"username": "myname", "password": "mypass"}`
   2. verify credentials
   3. if **OK** gives 200 and create a cookie with session
   4. if **NOT** gives 401
2. `GET /players`:

   1. check session in cookie
   2. if **OK** gives 200 with {"players": "[...]"}
   3. if **NOT** gives 401
3. `POST /player/1`:

   1. check session in cookie
   2. if **OK** gives 200 and edit player
   3. if **NOT** gives 401

My front-end app has:

1. `/login` page with a form (with `username` and `password` fields) for issue a `POST` request to `back.domain.com/login`
2. `/players` which request a `GET` request to `back.domain.com/players`
3. a button which issues a `POST` request to `back.domain.com/player/1`

#### **QUESTIONS**

1. Do I need CSRF protection in this scenario?

   I think **YES, I need** because an attacker can issue a request to `back.domain.com/player/1` from `malicious.site.com` and use my session cookie to edit player because I'm logged in (and I still have a session cookie) on my `domain.com`.
2. Do I need CSRF protection (e.g. an `X-CSRF-Token` header) when I the first time login on `back.domain.com/login`?

   1. In this scenario I still don't have any session cookie in my browser.
   2. And also I don't know where to get my CSRF token for `X-CSRF-Token` authorization header too.

   I read on https://fractalideas.com/blog/making-react-and-django-play-well-together-single-page-app-model they are creating a dedicated endpoint on back-end for this and [they explain](https://fractalideas.com/blog/making-react-and-django-play-well-together-single-page-app-model/#fn-7) it's not a security vulnerability.

**What do you think about?**

Comment: I'm not able to answer the question, but I got a similar scenario and would like to know whether you got any new insights.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

You DO need CSRF protection any time BOTH of the following are true:

- the browser is automatically providing the authentication mechanism (most common way this is done is with a cookie)
- the operation is state-changing on your backend

Of your three endpoints, only one meets both of those conditions.

`GET /players/`: get is not a state-changing operation. No CSRF protection needed.

`POST /player/1/`: authentication provided by cookie; post is state-changing. Needs CSRF protection!

`POST /login/`: the browser is not automatically providing the authentication information; it’s coming from data the user has intentionally typed in and submitted. No CSRF protection needed.

You’ll find other schools of thought - [this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412813/do-login-forms-need-tokens-against-csrf-attacks) indicates the possibility of privacy-violation attacks, but the method described stretches credulity a bit in my opinion. And in any case you are right - if your frontend and backend are being served by totally different servers, your frontend won’t have the CSRF token before the user logs in.

Comment: Can you specify more on the meaning of state-changing endpoints ?

Comment: If making an HTTP request could result in data being changed on the server, it is "state-changing". Usually anything besides GET, HEAD, and OPTIONS.

Technically a server can do whatever it wants with any HTTP request, so you could implement an endpoint that changes server state in response to a GET request, but to abide by the spec properly, you wouldn't do this. It's highly recommended to abide by the spec because browsers will do things like caching and preflight requests and so on and will assume some HTTP verbs are safe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Safe/HTTP

Comment: WOUld it be wise to create a public endpoint on the ```backed.api.com``` to issue tokens? Would it need to be only for authenticated users or for everyone?