# How to ignore csurf in auth route

Tags: node.js, csrf

i building an API to my React Native app. I trying add csrf protection with [csurf lib](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) but the doc dont teach how i can ignore my auth route. I have this routes: "/signIn", "/post". Both is "post" method. The code it is like this:

```
const csrf = require("csurf");

const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true,
});

route.post("/signIn", csrf({ cookie: true, ignoreMethods: ["POST"] }), Player.signIn);
route.post("/post/:to/:from", csrfProtection, Post.verify, Post.battle);
```

I imagine that if the user is not authenticated, he does not need a csrf token. But the middleware `csrf({ cookie: true, ignoreMethods: ["POST"] })` also ignores the "post" route and generates this error: `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token`.

If I remove the middleware from the "signIn" route, the following error occurs: `TypeError: req.csrfToken is not a function`

How i can ignore the route "signIn" and use the function "`res.cookie("_csrf", req.csrfToken());`" without making a mistake?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but [CSRF on log in page is a good and secure practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412813/do-login-forms-need-tokens-against-csrf-attacks)

Comment: So if I must have a csrf on the login screen, where would the first csrf come from? @EricWong

Comment: On the first login form render, probably in `route.get("/signIn", ....)`