# symfony generate CSRF code in diferent website for login?

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

i have website **A** is a static html page and website **B** is a symfony script .
i was trying to implement a login form in website **A** to website **B** using iframe . both website support https , but i've faced 2 issues , 1st issue is the security protocol in the browser will not allow me to send data between 2 website using https and not same domain .

2end. so i added the login form html codes into website **A** but when i attempt to login after redirecting to website **B** i've got and error from Symfony `invalid CSRF`.

is it possible i can generate CSRF code in website **A** or i should disable the `CSRF` protection in website **B** to make this work ?

Comment: CSRF tokens are intended to be unique (to a certain context), so that they can’t be guessed and replayed. Generating a single one for your static site would defeat the purpose. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350123/231316), along with others on the page, talks about why disabling CSRF on a login is not recommended.

Comment: @ChrisHaas but since CSRF token based on a combination is it possible i can generate 1 into the A website before i submit to B ?

Comment: If **A** is static, no. But if **A** can dynamically call **B** to get a token, then yes. I'm pretty certain that the call would need to be server side, too, although if the **A** server signed the request (once again, server side) then I think that it could be done client-side.

Comment: @ChrisHaas , yes A is a dynamic its a php version site , i believe i can make it call B to request a token , but how i can manage this on symfony ?